# why I always get "Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint"

Tags: python, facebook, access-token

I am new to facebook. Sorry if I missed some simple part. I can successfully get access_token by from

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=XXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXX

However, when I used it to do FQL query:

```
graph = GraphAPI(access_token=access_token, timeout=1000)
query1 = "SELECT id, username, name  FROM profile WHERE contains('Client Name') AND type='user'"
results = graph.fql(query1)
```

I got following error messages

facebook.GraphAPIError: Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint

I am using python facebook-sdk for development. Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Is your ``access_token`` valid?

Comment: How to tell it is valid or not? I got it from FB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving an [app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens):

> App access tokens are used to make requests to Facebook APIs on behalf of an app rather than a user. This can be used to modify the parameters of your app, create and manage test users, or read your application's insights.

You want to retrieve a [user token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens) instead.

Comment: Thanks. I try to use user token at beginning. However, when I perform query like: 
query2 = "SELECT email, first_name, last_name FROM standard_user_info WHERE uid IN (SELECT id FROM profile WHERE contains('client name') and type='user')"
It asked me to use app access token...

Comment: The `standard_user_info` table is for analytics information, so it requires app access tokens. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/standard_user_info/. If your application needs both kinds of tokens, there is no reason why you can't use both.

Comment: Thanks again! I am also confused that why I cannot use both. The script worked before. So strange.